# Task assignment in Microsoft Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on an app that needs to assign tasks to user in office365.

Is there a way to assign a task to a specific user without passing by Microsoft Planner?

I don't want to have to create plan and buckets to assign a user to a task.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Planner Tasks live within a Bucket, within a Plan. Without a Plan & Bucket, how would a user see the Task they are assigned in Planner?

Comment: I want to create a task but not in Planner, just a general task and assign it to a user

Comment: Where are you looking for these tasks to surface? In other words, how will the user know they have a task and how would they mark that task complete?

Comment: I send a request to this endpoint to create a task : https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/tasks but i cant assign it to a user.  Is there another route or endpoint to do it? But without planner stuff.  Like we can do in native outlook

Comment: Ah, okay. Outlook Tasks are something entirely different. Outlook has "Tasks" and Planner has "Tasks" but they are distinctly different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph has support for [Outlook Tasks](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktask) in the `/beta` release. This are accessible via the `/outlook/tasks` endpoint.

For example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks
```

Outlook Tasks shouldn't be confused with Planner Tasks. They are completely different. Outlook Tasks are stored within Exchange Online and surfaced within Outlook while Planner Tasks are entirely stored and surfaced within Microsoft Planner.

Comment: Ok and can I assign someone to a task created from this endpoint?

Comment: Outlook Tasks are single-user. If you want to create a Task for someone else then you need to place it in their mailbox using `/users/{id}/outlook/tasks`